# How to get p:dataTable id

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I need to get the p:dataTable object. But seems like I am not able to get the p:dataTable object using the below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var table2 = document.getElementById('test2_datatable_staffs_2');
</script>

<h:form id="form1" prependId="false">
    <p:dataTable id="test2_datatable_staffs_2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `widgetVar` instead of `id`.

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="test2_datatable_staffs_2">
```

You can access PrimeFaces elements in JavaScript the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   var table2 = PF('test2_datatable_staffs_2');
</script>
```

Give this a try and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The id of the `h:form` is being prepended to your `p:dataTable`

You can use the following code

```
    var table2 = document.getElementById('form1:test2_datatable_staffs_2');
```

Or just set the `prependId=false` for the `h:form` and use your current code

Comment: I have added prependId="false". But it returns me a div instead of the dataTable object.

Comment: That means that my answer is right :) , since the JSF `<p:dataTable` element is actually a HTML `div` with `table` inside.

Comment: the table tag inside the div won't have a id? I saw its only role=grid. Cause I need to get that table id. Not too sure if that is even possible.

Comment: It looks like you need rephrase a new question in which you should ask how to achieve your goal in general

Answer (score 0):

that cause JSF put the form name before the table id

you should use

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var table2 = document.getElementById('form1\\:test2_datatable_staffs_2');
</script>
```